# Initiating Vue.js Variable as Server Generated Value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, variables

Really struggling to find a solution to what to me seems like a really simple and common use case. I'm building a Laravel/VueJS app which is using Axios to make API call. However, I want to use Laravel to set the base url (based on what's defined in the .env file) so that I can push my code seamlessly from my localhost to staging and then production.

In short this is what I want to do:

in the HTML (blade) file:

```
base_url = {{ url('/') }} //Set the varible using the sever generated value
```

In the Vue app:

```
axios
.post( base_url + 'todo/save/') //on mounted() when the first API call is made retreive the serve generated value
...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Mikael

Comment: Is there a reason you need a full URL? If you're making a request to the same server, you can just do `axios.get('/todo/save')` and it will default to using `location.host` of the user's browser.

Comment: @LannyBose won't work if the app isn't running from the document root

Comment: You could pass it to your component to use it in axios like this: ```<my-component :baseUrl="{{ env('MY_ENVVAR') }}"></my-component>```

Comment: You can do it by adding a `MIX` keyword before the variable name in your .env file, e.g. `MIX_BASE_URL`. Then in your vue component, you can access it like this `process.env.MIX_BASE_URL`. 

Don't forget to restart your local server when changing value in .env file.

Comment: thanks, everyone! I'll probably refer to Lanny's solution for now as it does the job and will look into those other suggestions I feel I might need to pass varibles from PHP to Vue in the future too (not related to url perhaps).